# What's a good site for sorting spell on class lists

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rogue, eldritch-knight

I am currently counting and comparing all of the known spells of classes, and have hit a brick wall with Arcane Trickster Rogue and Eldritch Knight Fighter.

**What Site can sort spells down to type and spell level, or just choose Arcane Trickster and Eldritch Knight so I can count their spell list.**

*not sure if it helps but only looking for their actual list excluding the spells from any school they can learn*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can use D&D Beyond

On [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/class/wizard) you can go to the Wizard spell list, and then use the Advanced Filters to filter by spellschool. For an Eldritch Knight, you simply filter by Wizard, and then by Abjuration & Evocation, resulting in the [following list](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/class/wizard?filter-search=&filter-school=3&filter-school=7&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=).

The spell list is automatically sorted by spell level, so you should be able to easily find what spells are available for you at what level.

**Note:** This will not actually give you the full list of spells available to them, because at certain levels, they can pick any spell from the Wizard spell list. But it will largely solve the issue of 'what spell can I pick at what spell level?'.

Comment: Tha is for answer and yeah they both get a total of 4 from the entire list ^.^ I don't wanna make an answer [here's this] [1] but you can add this in that I came across just moment ago!                       [1]:https://amp-reddit-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/amp.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/35pv3n/arcane_trickster_and_eldritch_knight_spell_lists/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCCAE%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FDnD%2Fcomments%2F35pv3n%2Farcane_trickster_and_eldritch_knight_spell_lists%2F

Comment: "The spell list is automatically sorted by spell level" - for me, it's always been automatically sorted alphabetically...

Comment: @NathanS Weird, for me personally, it's sorted by spell level. There might be a way to change the sorting then. Deceptecium: While that list might be correct, it won't stay correct. The D&D Beyond method is far more likely to stay up to date than a premade list somebody compiled at some point.

Comment: Do you have a twitch account? I don't, so I'm looking at the free, not-logged-in version of D&DBeyond. Maybe if you have an account, there might be some settings somewhere that changes the default sorting? If that's not it, then that was my only guess as to why it's different. So as you said, weird...

Comment: @Rubiksmoose It is free, though? The list should be able to show you all the spells from all content, it just won't allow you to read the description if you don't own the content. Any list which does allow that would be stealing copyrighted work and therefore not allowed on this stackexchange to begin with.

Comment: @Theik oops yeah you're totally right. Forgot that it showed you them just didn't allow you to read.

Comment: https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells (like similar listings) does indeed sort alphabetically by default, but you can sort/filter the list and then copy the URL; those who click on that URL will be shown the page with the same sorting/filtering options applied.